# Wordpress is generating an empty list item in primary menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to design a theme in Wordpress and have run into an issue with my primary menu. Wordpress is generating an empty list item and upon inspection, I can't understand why.

**functions.php**

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
));
```

**header.php**

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head> 
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Treet</title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="container">
<!-- Site Header -->
<header class="site-header">
    <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
    <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>

    <nav class="mainNav">
        <?php 

            $args = array (
                'theme_location' => 'primary'
            );

        ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
    </nav>

</header>
```

**style.css**

```
/* Navigation Menus */

nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
}

nav ul:before, nav ul:after {
content: "";
display: table;
}

nav ul:after {
clear: both;
}

.site-header nav ul li a {
padding: 10px 10px;
display: block;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
border-bottom: none;
}
```

And finally, here are two screenshots of what's happening.

**Result**: [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/5c92f521a2e421bc85838a13fd8c2a39)

**Inspect**: [inspectScreenshot](https://gyazo.com/e72ec6f9bc86bbac04fcbe20f4b4c89d)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no closing tag for your link inside h1 ;)